# Exporting React Native app for web (HTML/JavaScript)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I’ve built a small app with React Native and it looks awesome, but I was wondering - can I just export it for web (HTML/JavaScript) instead making a separate code in ReactJS for it? And if it’s possible, what are the pros and cons? BTW I used a free UI kit for the developing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) and share 90% the same source code, between native and webapp.

   - Good for non-complex projects;
   - If your app have native/complex navigation, then it will have issues, because this can't work on web.
2. Use web `react` and share some components.

   - Recommended for complex projects;
   - If you have a complex native app, share the components can be the best option;
   - [bit.dev](https://bit.dev/) can be useful to achieve this solution.

More info: 
https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-share-and-reuse-react-components-6d80e2fd16cd

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Expo](https://expo.dev/) to build for any platform: IOS, Android, Web 
For the web, you can use `expo build:web` 
It creates a production ready static bundle in the `web-build/` directory
[Here is the full document for the web](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/publishing-websites/#creating-a-build)